# How to create a module-global internal variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to create a static variable in my module. How can I do that? Can I use `our` or `state`?

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
use MyModule;
MyModule::increase_count(); # should return 0
MyModule::increase_count(); # should return 1
MyModule::increase_count(); # should return 2
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use `state` (which is a good idea):

```
package MyModule;

# return the previous value
sub increase_count {
  state $count = 0;
  return $count++;
}
```

Using `state` minimizes the visibility of the symbol. If you have to share the visibility accross multiple subs, you can enclose a lexical variable in a block:

```
{
  my $count = 0;
  sub increase_count { $count++ }
  sub current_count  { $count   }
  sub decrease_count { $count-- }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you do not use a `BEGIN` block there for that block, you have no guarantee that the variable will be initialized before its functions can be called.  In this case it makes little enough difference, but in the general one it certainly does so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `$counter` variable directly outside of `MyModule` package, use `our`, but if you don't then `my` is what should be used,

```
package MyModule;

my $counter = 0;
sub increase_count {

  return $counter++;
}
```